Ports forwards exist on router even when Port forward option is set to No
I have a strange situation.
i have a router Asus DSL-AX82.
Today i login to router and i was exploring the logs sections inside router.
I was very surprised when on Port Forwarding log i see 2 port forwards TCP 37120 and TCP 37209
The 2 ports are forwarded on a local ip address , and this address was the address of one of my PC.I checked and the ports are open.
But anyone inside my house did not configured those ports forwards.
But when i go in router menus to the section when port forward can be configured , the option "Enable port forwarding" is set to NO , and i can't see any port forward here. but on logs section the 2 ports remain forwarded.
I change the local IP on the Pc where the port is forwarded , and i restart the router , after that even on logs section there are no port forwarding anymore.
And of course i change the admin password on router.
But i want to know how this is possible , with Port forward option set to no , and port forwarding exist .And what about those 2 port numbers ? Is there any default program that can use these ? Because using netstat command on destination Pc , there are no results for both ports.

ports open because processes open them. a port is always closed if no process has created and opened it, regardless of routers and firewalls. it sounds like you are seeing established connections rather than ports that are in a listening state, or ports that are accessible from the WAN side of the router. start by looking at the process that opened those ports. its possible that it uses UPNP to open up ports, or that it establishes a reverse tunnel, or they may just be plain old outbound connections.

@FrankThomas The log inside router is labeled Port forward , and there there are 2 lines for Port forward With Port Number , Protocol , Local IP of destination PC.

I recommend that you go to that PC, and run a command like netstat -a | findstr 37120 to see the details of the connection. the last item on the line should be the PID of the process that owns that port. you can then run tasklist /SVC | findstr <pid> to find the name of the process, or use Process Explorer. basically identifying the software that is responsible for the questionable configuration is the first step in figuring out the who/what/why/where/when of the mystery.

@FrankThomas I've already run that command  netstat -a | findstr 37120, but the result is empty. Nothing is shown.

do the logs indicate that 37120 and 37209 are mapped to a different port on your LAN system?

@FrankThomas as i remember yes , the log has the format  :  Source,           Destination  ,    Proto. Port range  ,   Redirect to  ,     Local port  .

did you check the PC for the local port, or the remote port?

@FrankThomas I think i check for the Port range , 37120 and 37209.

well, if the software is still running on the PC, it will be on the local ports, not the remote ports. have you tried powercycling the router? do these traces you are seeing disappear when you do so? also, have you considered disabling UPNP on your router if that is possible for your model?

@FrankThomas I changed  local ip address on destination Pc , after i restart the router and after that the port forwarded on log are disappeared.. My only concern is , if this may be a hacker attack ?

if your router is not configured for external management, and has a reasonably strong non-default password, then if there is any malfeasance, it is almost certainly coming from malware running inside your network. since you were not able to identify the cause or target of the concerning log entries, that is about all that we can discern at this time.

@FrankThomas I don't think it's a malware inside network. All the pcs have Norton 360 Deluxe installed and updated regulary , with firewall enabled....No pirate software inside.
